# provide EF Core access by a random link

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

To allow access certain areas I want to provide a non-guessable link like the non-listed video links of youtube or anonymous links to onedrive resources.

`https://myapp.com/a123hddvn321gv3a/enroll`

Would be nice to use build it stuff like Attributes for controllers to apply that special access.

I am pretty sure there is a name for that and may be a special kind of identity in the ASP.NET world. My googleing did not make me find the right hint.
Can you point to it?

Comment: Similar to a two-factor or request verification token? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages

Comment: yes, but I want the token in a GET request

Comment: So a route parameter, either matching a random value in a database column, or derived from other query parameters?

Comment: yes, either a virtual route or a query string. can be impemented quite easy, but I have the feeling to invent the wheel again.